# Spring boot with Mockito mocking NamedParameterJdbcTemplate

Tags: spring, spring-boot, mockito, junit-jupiter, namedparameterjdbctemplate

Trying to unit test a method which is defined as :

```
public void myMethod(List<? extends MyModel> model){
  int[] result = namedParameterJdbcTemplate.batchUpdate("update query", SqlParameterSourceUtils.createBatch(model));
}
```

In my test class i am defining test method as

```
class MyTestClass{

  @Mock
  NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate;
   
  @InjectMocks
  MyDao dao;

  @Test
  public void testMyMethod() {

    final int[] rowsAffected = new int[]{1,2};

    when(namedParameterJdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(any(), SqlParameterSourceUtils.createBatch(Arrays.asList(anySet())))).thenReturn(rowsAffected);
        
    List<MyModel> myModels = new ArrayList<>();
    MyModel mymodel = new MyModel();
    mymodel.setSomeParam("");
    myModels.add(mymodel);
    dao.myMethod(myModels);
        
  }
}
```

While running this test method , i am getting NullPointerException in called method(myMethod()). int[] result is coming as null. My understanding is it should get the result from the stub in the mock.
Please help me understand what am i doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're not using the correct import for `any()` because if it would be the correct `ArgumentMatchers.any()` from Mockito, Mockito would complain that you don't use an `ArgumentMatcher` for both parameters of `.batchUpdate()`.

You can statically import it with `import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.*;`  or use `ArgumentMatchers.any()`.

So as first step, try the following:

```
when(namedParameterJdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(ArgumentMatchers.any(), ArgumentMatchers.any())).thenReturn(rowsAffected);
```

or be less *generic* and match the return type of `SqlParameterSourceUtils.createBatch()` with:

```
// I don't know what SqlParameterSourceUtils.createBatch() returns, so you might have to adjust it
when(namedParameterJdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(ArgumentMatchers.any(), ArgumentMatchers.eq("SOME RETURN"))).thenReturn(rowsAffected);
```

Comment: Thank You for your inputs.I had already tried your recommendation but apparently on doing so i start getting compile time error as "Ambiguous method call. Both
batchUpdate
(String,
Map<String, ?>[])
in NamedParameterJdbcTemplate and
batchUpdate
(String,
SqlParameterSource[])
in NamedParameterJdbcTemplate match". 
Also for second recommendation similar compilation error appears.
Any other recommendation?

Comment: Can you Update you question and and your SqlParameterSourceUtils class?

Comment: Found the solution , adding the cast to ArgumentMatchers worked.
  when(namedParameterJdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(anyString(), (SqlParameterSource[]) any())).thenReturn(rowsAffected);

Answer (score 0):

It worked by adding the cast to the Argument matchers:
Updated Code :

```
    when(namedParameterJdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(anyString(), (SqlParameterSource[]) any())).thenReturn(rowsAffected);
```